# Helping monks overcome non-synergy class abilities

Tags: pathfinder-1e, house-rules, monk

So most people agree that in Pathfinder the monk suffers in many ways, most commonly MAD and abilities that dont exactly work together, such as their fast movement and flurry of blows.

To help the monk out, what do people think of the ability to exchange an attack from the flurry of blows for either 1/4, 1/2, or all the movement you can gain from fast movement (and yes, you can do this several times)? This should give monks some needed versatility when it comes to using flurry of blows and their need to move around the battle field. It also helps give a monk more battle field control as they can attack, move, attack, move if there are lots of weak enemies, or just in using combat maneuvers.

I see that someone has already tried addressing movement and attack here [Making monks better but not broken](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37435/making-monks-better-but-not-broken)

Comment: This is not a general debate on monks.  This is a question about whether this specific house rule would help with them, which is on topic.  Keep in mind however our site rules on answering house rules questions (experience not armchair analysis). http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/942/how-to-deal-with-feedback-questions-about-house-rules

Comment: That is an interesting link you posted. I had not known about the thread/article.

Comment: Sure.  As new on the site, you might want to review all the FAQs on meta. http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq

Comment: Note: I voted to close as opinion-based because this question asks "What do people think of this houserule?" To be an objectively answerable question, I feel some stronger criteria are needed, something along the lines of "Does this really help fix the monk's problems? Is this balanced? Does it have negative side effects?" Right now all we have is a request for feedback.

Comment: So changing it slightly to asking about its balance or its negative side effects is better?

Comment: @Fering That's up to you; you should think about what you actually want answered about this houserule and change your question to reflect that. Right now, any and all feedback would be a legitimate answer to your question, and that doesn't work well for this site.

Comment: I would rather the post be helpful or useful then one which is in danger of being closed. With that being the case, I am open to suggestions on all my questions, answers, and comments.

Comment: The problem is that if you ask *Will giving the monk this new thing be unbalanced?*, unless it's crazy (e.g. SLA 3/day — *wish*), no one will say *Yes* because monks are so poorly designed that giving monks *one* reasonable thing *can't* unbalance them. But, for example, if you want a serious critique of your homebrew monk, that's better done by an actual forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Anything helps, but it’s not enough

I have played in a game with a monk who could flurry as a standard action (as a houserule), and *many* games with monks who could either move as a swift action or could flurry after a charge (since these things are relatively easy to get in the games I play/DM). These things are all superior to what you propose, and they don’t do enough. They fix *a* problem, but by far not the biggest ones.

#### Houserule analysis: basically a fancy Spring Attack

In general, Pathfinder has made is even more difficult than it was in 3.5 to move and keep up one’s mundane offense in the same round.<sup>1</sup> This, in my opinion, is not just bad for the game, but awful for it.

So I support improvement in the ability to move and full-attack at the same time, for all classes, but perhaps most of all for the monk; after all, the monk is the quintessential mobile attacker. Your houserule would allow the monk – after several levels – to basically use Spring Attack, and then at much higher levels, a Spring Attack with a couple of attacks in it. That’s a fighting style that makes some sense and synergizes much better with his class abilities, but this monk is losing 2 attacks to do it: that’s a lot. The monk is a very-low-damage class; his jumping in and out to pester enemies is probably just going to get ignored. And by jumping away, he is eliminating any chance he has at being a battlefield presence between his turns.

#### Monk role analysis, post-houserule: wannabe harrier?

It sounds like you want to make the monk into a harrier, which might be about as close to a role as the monk has ever had. Ultimately, the monk is a very passive, defensive class package. If enemies attempt to chase him down or corner him, he can make that fairly difficult for them (at least, relative to the standards of mundane characters). These are features that a harrier wants.

But a harrier needs to be sufficiently debilitating to the enemy that they *want* to chase him down and eliminate him. The monk just doesn’t provide that. Particularly with this houserule, the monk can move in and out, taking its free attacks with impunity, and the enemy can (and should) *just ignore him.* Because the monk lacks anything sufficiently worrisome to be worth the effort chasing him down. Even its standout offensive feature, unarmed strike damage, is really more of a defense against being stripped of your weapons, since even a monk’s unarmed strike is a fairly mediocre weapon. Flurry of blows is somewhat better, but the attack penalties and general MAD problems mean that the monk has neither the accuracy nor the damage to make it scary.

And its defensive features don’t lend themselves to taking fire for your allies, so it’s not like you can tank. Monk class features lend themselves to staying out of harm’s way in the first place: that can be nice for you, but it does nothing for your allies. The features of the monk allow you to survive, but give you little to offer your allies in or out of combat.

#### Conclusion

So fixing the monk means, first and foremost, deciding *what the monk should be doing for its allies*, what role the monk should have in play. It currently has none; it mostly allows you to safely sit out. And building the monk up to that role is going to involve some significant revision to the class. If you want to make the monk a harrier, you have to give it some way of being problematic enough for the enemy to be worth taking the time to focus on him. Then, and only then, do his greater mobility and defenses become valuable, because enemies are forced to put more time and effort into just cornering him, and the rest of the party is now that much freer to act.

Now, with all this in mind, you are looking at a lot of work. As an alternative, there are a couple of decent monk archetypes. Moreover, classes like cleric, magus, and if using third-party material, Dreamscarred Press’s psychic warrior, make *great* monks, whether as a harrier or otherwise. So does porting the 3.5 swordsage from *Tome of Battle* to Pathfinder (I suggest, for the swordsage anyway, that you use Sense Motive in place of Concentration for Diamond Mind). These are always going to be my suggestions. The core monk, and the majority of its archetypes, are just not worth saving. They were a flawed design from the beginning, and superior alternatives with a matching narrative role are abundant.

---

1. <sup>Compare: a totem barbarian can get pounce at level 10, if he selects three specific Rage Powers. A synthesist summoner can it at *3rd* and it costs him way less (aside from the cost of being a synthesist, since that archetype is generally weaker than a regular summoner). Or, for that matter, every spellcaster in the game, aside perhaps from the magus, doesn’t *care*, because their spells take a standard action, and thus they can move and maintain their best spellcasting anyway. And the right spell can do more than all the attacks in the world in many cases.</sup>